# Information on the moderator candidates

Tags: discussion, election

[Yi Jiang](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150097/yi-jiang) has put together a nice site that use the Stack Overflow API to display information on the moderator candidates.

[Click here to see all the information.](http://184.106.81.14/)

The information presented is:

The nominees election

```
Answers/Questions on the main site and it's meta
Up-vote/down-vote ratio
Average reputation earned per post
Average reputation earned per day.
```

It displays what Yi Jiang considers to be noteworthy badges and whether the nominee has the badge and a summary of their recent activity.

The information is presented as is with no commentary.

It came about from this question on MSO [Moderator nomination possibly useful statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75454/59303)

**I blatantly copied this exactly from [Rory Alsop](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/2077/rory-alsop)'s [post on meta.Security.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/542/information-on-the-moderator-candidates)**

Comment: +1 for blatantly copying...I copied mine from a much earlier MSO post :-)